# How can I use 2 range sliders at the same time?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I want to filter data in the table based on the age and height at the same time using 2 range sliders.

I have implemented 2 range sliders (Age and Height) using [d3.slider.js](https://github.com/MasterMaps/d3-slider) and a `dc.dataTable`. I want to use these 2 range sliders at the same time, but it seems that they are not working properly.

Also, under the table, there is the text "49 selected out of 49 records". The numbers are not changing while using the sliders.

Code:

```
    var dataTable = dc.dataTable("table#list");
    var dispatch = d3.dispatch('load','filter');

    d3.json('data.json',function(json){
        dispatch.load(json)
    });

    dispatch.on('load',function(json) {
        var formatNumber = d3.format( ",d");
        var facts = crossfilter(json);
        var dimensionAge = facts.dimension(function(d) {
            return +d.age;
        });
        var accessorAge = function(d) {
            return d.age;
        };
        var dimensionHeight = facts.dimension(function(d) {
            return +d.height;
        });
        var accessorHeight = function(d) {
            return d.height;
        };
        var range = d3.extent(json, accessorAge);
        var range2 = d3.extent(json, accessorHeight);
        var all = facts.groupAll();

        d3.select("div#slider3")
            .call(d3.slider().axis(true).min(range[0]).max(range[1]).value(range)
            .on("slide", function(evt,value) {
                dispatch.filter(value);
                d3.select("#slider3textmin").text(Math.floor(value[0]));
                d3.select("#slider3textmax").text(Math.floor(value[1]))
            }))

        d3.select("div#slider4")
            .call(d3.slider().axis(true).min(range2[0]).max(range2[1]).value(range2)
            .on("slide", function(evt,value) {
                dispatch.filter(value);
                d3.select("#slider4textmin").text(Math.floor(value[0]));
                d3.select("#slider4textmax").text(Math.floor(value[1]))
            }))


        FieldNames = [
            "",
            "Age",
            "Weight",
            "Height",
            "Eye Color",
            "Hair Color",
            "Race",
            "Sex",
            "Annual Income"
        ];

        d3.select("tr#FieldNames").selectAll("th")
            .data(FieldNames)
            .enter()
            .append("th") 
            .append("text")
            .text(function(d){ 
                return d;
            });

        dataTable
            .dimension(dimensionAge)
            .group(function(d) {
                return d.sex;
            })
            .columns([
                function(d) {return "";},
                function(d) {return d.age;},
                function(d) {return d.weight;},
                function(d) {return d.height;},
                function(d) {return d.eyeColor;},
                function(d) {return d.hairColor;},
                function(d) {return d.race;},
                function(d) {return d.sex;},
                function(d) {return formatNumber(d.annualIncome);}
            ]);   

        dispatch.on('filter',function(value){
            dataTable.replaceFilter(dc.filters.RangedFilter(value[0], value[1]));
            dataTable.redraw();
        })

        dc.dataCount(".dc-data-count")
            .dimension(facts)
            .group(all);

        dc.renderAll();

    });
```

[Link to the website](http://d3.magnetica-hosting.sk/sortable-table-with-slider.html)

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Di9O8w5NkDOIoh9fL1qW?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Original response [on the dc.js users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/dc-js-user-group/cyyqE7yuxQk/nnOYmZZmAgAJ).

> Nice use of d3.slider.js - I haven't seen that used with dc.js before.
>
> At a quick glance, I see two problems here. First, you're using one
>   dispatch for both sliders, so both sliders are filtering the age,
>   since that's the dimension of the table. You'd probably want to create
>   another dimension for filtering by height, and you don't really need
>   to attach that to a chart.
>
> Second, instead of just redrawing the chart with dataTable.redraw(),
>   you probably want to call dataTable.redrawGroup() so that all charts
>   in its chart group get redrawn, including the dataCount.

Specifically:

1. you'll need two filter events in your dispatch

   ```
   var dispatch = d3.dispatch('load','filterAge','filterHeight');
   ```
2. the age slider will call filterAge

   ```
               dispatch.filterAge(value);
   ```

   and the height slider will call filterHeight

   ```
               dispatch.filterHeight(value);
   ```
3. the current `filter` event handler will now handle `filterAge` and it will call `redrawGroup`

   ```
       dispatch.on('filterAge',function(value){
           dataTable.replaceFilter(dc.filters.RangedFilter(value[0], value[1]));
           dataTable.redrawGroup();
       })
   ```
4. we add another `filterHeight` handler which directly filters `dimensionHeight` and also redraws the chart group

   ```
       dispatch.on('filterHeight',function(value){
           dimensionHeight.filter([value[0], value[1]]);
           dataTable.redrawGroup();
       })
   ```
5. **Reset All** will also have to clear `dimensionHeight`. (Since this dimension isn't used by any chart, `dc.filterAll()` won't find it.)

   ```
           <a href="javascript: dimensionHeight.filter(null); dc.filterAll(); dc.renderAll();">Reset All</a>
   ```

[Fork of your plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LKTE577KX8bb7SGlhY64?p=preview).

Comment: Could you also, please, solve the problem with the text "49 selected out of 49 records" under the table? When I am using the Age slider, the numbers are not changing at all. And also the link "Reset All" is not working properly.

Comment: Failed to save the `redrawGroup` change for `filterAge` because I'm not used to Plunker. Fixed that, and added **Reset All** to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

this for reset all, the 49 selected out of 49 records already change correcly

replace this

```
<a href="javascript: dimensionHeight.filter(null); dc.filterAll(); dc.renderAll();">Reset All</a>
```

to this

```
<a href="#" onclick="sololo()">Reset All</a>
```

add this after dispatch on load

```
dispatch.on('load',function(json) {
//your code
})       

function sololo(){
                   //table
               dispatch.filterAge([0,100]);
               dispatch.filterHeight([0,100]);
               //text slider
               d3.select("#slider4textmin").text(0)
                     d3.select("#slider4textmax").text(0)
                     d3.select("#slider3textmin").text(0);
                     d3.select("#slider3textmax").text(0)
                     //slider
                     d3.select('#slider3').select('#handle-one').style('left','0%')
               d3.select('#slider3').select('#handle-two') .style('right','0%')
               d3.select('#slider3').select('div').style('left','0%').style('right','0%') 
                     d3.select('#slider4').select('#handle-one').style('left','0%')
               d3.select('#slider4').select('#handle-two') .style('right','0%')
               d3.select('#slider4').select('div').style('left','0%').style('right','0%') 
    }
```

Comment: Good point about resetting the sliders. Oof, is that the only way to do it?

Comment: mmmm.... you not draw slider manually you using liblary, so the best thing is to inject on html element , you can use loop, you can remove that slider and draw it again, or using build up function on that slider.js to do that if there is one

Comment: I poked into d3.slider.js a little bit and indeed it looks like there is no good API for this - it allows updating the value but it expects the value is scalar, and crashes if you pass an array for updates. So I think this is best solution for the sliders for now. One part seems to be missing - this doesn't reset the right slider, just the blue background.