# d3 chart + jQuery DataTables: trouble reading nested array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, d3.js, datatables

I'm trying to adapt [this jQuery DataTables example](http://plnkr.co/edit/QHNpIpV8UTjIsWL4joJT?p=preview) to a d3 chart that I've been developing.

Here's a link to the semi-working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kXvBjNsCbblC3ykkuPsL?p=preview

The problem is that some of the values are showing up in the table, while others are not (in particular, the values that come from an array within an array).
Oddly enough, the error message I'm getting, `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`, refers to line 1074, on which `recordCol` is defined. This is strange because the values for `recordCol` and `stateName` both show up just fine in the DataTable. Also strange is that all of the column headers do appear, even for the nested array (though not their values).

Here's the problematic code:

```
function tables(dataset) {

    var recordCol = Object.keys(dataset[0])[0];
    var stateName = Object.keys(dataset[0])[3];
    var dateCol = Object.keys(dataset[0].values[0])[0];
    var valCol = Object.keys(dataset[0].values[0])[1];

    var monthDateFormat = d3.time.format("%B");
    var yearDateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y");
    var properDateFormat = d3.time.format("%B %Y");
  
      var tableData = dataset.map(function(d) {
        d[recordCol] = d[recordCol].toString().slice(0, 15);
        d[stateName] = d[stateName].toString().slice(0, 20);
        d[dateCol] = d[dateCol];//.toString().slice(0, 20);   
        d[valCol] = d[valCol];///.toString().slice(0, 20);        

        return d;
      })

    $(".data-table").empty();

    if (dataTable) {
    dataTable.destroy();
    }

    dataTable = $(".data-table").DataTable({
      data: tableData,
      columns: [{
        "data": recordCol
      }, {
        "data": stateName
      }, {
        "data": dateCol
      }, {            
        "data": valCol        
      }]
    });

      d3.selectAll("thead th").each(function(d, i) {
        if (i === 0) {
          this.textContent = recordCol;
        } else if (i === 1) {
          this.textContent = stateName;
        } else if (i === 2) {
          this.textContent = dateCol; 
        } else if (i === 3) {
          this.textContent = valCol;          
        }
      });      
}
```

As you'll see in [my semi-working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kXvBjNsCbblC3ykkuPsL?p=preview), I've been beating a dead horse in console.log, trying to troubleshoot the error messages I've been getting, the other of which is [this](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4#Diagnosis).

In sum,  what I'm trying to do is get all the values for `x` and `y` to appear in the DataTable alongside `state` and `record` -- as well as relabel the column headers that currently read `x` and `y` as as `date` and `value`, respectively.

In advance, thanks very much for any assistance you're able to offer.

**Update:**

The following changes, I've discovered, make the full subarray, containing all the `x` and `y` values, appear in every row of the DataTable:

```
  dataTable = $(".data-table").DataTable({
    data: tableData,
    columns: [{
      "data": recordCol
    }, {
      "data": stateName
    }, {
      "data": "values[, ].x" 
    }, {            
      "data": "values[, ].y"  
    }]
  });
```

Here's an [updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8bMZEZdKAmoKC5hittoi?p=preview). The search for a solution continues.

**Update 2:**
The following changes make the `x` and `y` value appear as `Sun May 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` and `2761`, **but the same in every row**:

```
  var tableData = dataset.map(function(d) {
    d[recordCol] = d[recordCol].toString().slice(0, 15);
    d[stateName] = d[stateName].toString().slice(0, 20);
  for (var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {  
    d[dateCol] = dataset[0].values[i].x;
    d[valCol] = dataset[0].values[i].y;       
  } 

  dataTable = $(".data-table").DataTable({
    data: tableData,
    columns: [{
      "data": recordCol
    }, {
      "data": stateName
    }, {
      "data": dateCol 
    }, {            
      "data": valCol  
    }]
  });
```

Another [updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SqTUrgxIrxVz9EedBIoa?p=preview). Obviously, this is wrong; still searching for a solution.

**Update 3:**

Still searching for a solution, but in this [third updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MFzh5tdtVNG47t4H2nCi?p=preview), I discovered how to take all of the values contained in the subarray of the parent array's first row, and (incorrectly) map them onto all of the rows of the parent array. Here's an illustration of what's going wrong:[image]

Is anyone able to demonstrate a solution?

Comment: your dataset is undefined, maybe the problem is on your table() on end of script, because in your script you say table(dataset) function(){ } but you call table() where is the dataset

Comment: I think you're mistaken. `dataset` shows up fine in the function when called with `console.log` Otherwise, two of the four columns of data wouldn't be showing up correctly, as they presently do, in the table. Also, `table(dataset)` appears on line 124.

Comment: Here's a screenshow demonstrating that dataset is correctly defined:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXcr4.png Istriku dari Bekasi; salam dari AS ya

Comment: I think recordCol should be record  and stateCol should be state in your dataset!

Comment: Can you show me what you mean?

Comment: You can see a problem (here)[http://plnkr.co/edit/68ZOTUjyj2VJpjxUXmdI] on line 1125

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how to turn the problem you're indicating into a solution.

Comment: @LaissezPasser I was just trying to steer you in the right direction, I'll have a look at it further if I get some time.

Comment: Thanks very much; I'll keep at it, too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46024705/how-can-i-use-2-range-sliders-at-the-same-time/46048358 , try understand this, maybe it will help sorting your data table and getting value, salam juga dari sini, ya

Comment: So, just to be clear, you've got an array of objects which you want to use to populate your table? Each object has a Code, a Record and a set of key-value pairs with a date being the key and a number being the value? And what do you want to see in the table? Each date-number pair being beside the code and record?

Comment: Exactly. Each date (`x`)-number(`y`) pair beside their respective state and code, keyed as you describe.

Comment: So instead of a table with 30 rows, it would have 3,270 rows (i.e., 10 states * 3 record codes * 109 dates-number pairs = 3,270 rows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your table map. Try it:

```
var table_map = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {  
    for (var j = 0; j < dataset[i].values.length; j++) {  

      var table_row = {};
      table_row[recordCol] = dataset[i][recordCol];
      table_row[stateName] = dataset[i][stateName];

      table_row[dateCol] = dataset[i].values[j][dateCol];
      table_row[valCol] = dataset[i].values[j][valCol];

      table_map.push(table_row);
    }
  }
```

[image: Plunker Test]

Comment: For future researchers with the same problem, a working, final Plunker is available here: http://plnkr.co/edit/5WAdq0dOXy16cb3BKPLZ?p=preview. Beautiful solution; thank you!